# Hex digit to binary with only 4 digits

Tags: java, binary, hex, converters

int[] LETTERS = {0x69F99}

I want to convert every single hex digit to binary, for example the 1st hex digit from the 1st hex string (6):

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(LETTERS[0]);
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(hex.charAt(0));
System.out.println(binary);
```

OUTPUT:110110

If I do this Integer.toBinaryString(6) the output will be 110, but I want something with 4 digits, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just pad the string as appropriate with your favorite library or a utility function.

With Guava:

```
String binary = Strings.padStart(Integer.toBinaryString(hex.charAt(0)), 4, '0'));
```

Another option would be to simply fill a character buffer and render it as a string, which is essentially what the [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toUnsignedString%28int%2Cint%29) does:

```
public static String intToBin(int num) {
    char[] buf = new char[4];
    buf[0] = num & 0x1;
    buf[1] = num & 0x2;
    buf[2] = num & 0x4;
    buf[3] = num & 0x8;
    return new String(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no string here - just an array with one int so you essentially try to convert this integer into nibbles and this can be done this way:

```
int num = 0x12345678;

String bin32 = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(num)).replace(" ", "0");
System.out.printf("all 32bits=[%s]\n", bin32);

for(int nibble = 0; nibble < 32; nibble += 4)
{
    System.out.printf("nibble[%d]=[%s]\n", nibble, bin32.subSequence(nibble, nibble+4));
}
```

gives:

```
all 32bits=[00010010001101000101011001111000]
nibble[0]=[0001] ie hex digit 1 as bin
nibble[4]=[0010] ie hex digit 2 as bin
nibble[8]=[0011]
nibble[12]=[0100]
nibble[16]=[0101]
nibble[20]=[0110]
nibble[24]=[0111]
nibble[28]=[1000] ie hex digit 8 as bin
```